# Union retains both values in case of int with double

Tags: c, unions

I found out that Unions in C can hold an object of the same type at the same time and the memory overlaps. But in the course of experiments, I found that in the case of int and double, the memory does not intersect and both retain their original value.
I do not understand why?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

union Data
{
  int int_val;
  double d_val;
};

int main()
{
  union Data data = {0};
  data.d_val = 0;
  data.int_val = INT_MAX;
  printf("%f, %d\n", data.d_val, data.int_val);
  data.d_val = __DBL_MAX__;
  data.int_val = 0;
  printf("%f, %d\n", data.d_val, data.int_val);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I was expecting that changing value of one will corrupt the value of another;

I get this:

> gcc -g -o main main.c

```
0.000000, 2147483647
179769227765543015871544843204898548561652852981845720830741485657701606177416873137818677866537230765451463672297559953407043753842793767107723942762853526789169461948323286682454336232649253620483947928451548544466350813686932742283772637216475668546847194115014476747609904655041063083840261631978879582208.000000, 0
```

Comment: Try different values.

Comment: The second test *has* corrupted the `double` value. If you remove the `data.int_val = 0;` you get a different result for the `double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But in the course of experiments, I found that in the case of int and double, the memory does not intersect and both retain their original value.

No such finding is supported by the reported experiment. The value reported for `d_val` in the second case is 179769227765543015871544843204898548561652852981845720830741485657701606177416873137818677866537230765451463672297559953407043753842793767107723942762853526789169461948323286682454336232649253620483947928451548544466350813686932742283772637216475668546847194115014476747609904655041063083840261631978879582208.000000, but the actual `__DBL_MAX__` value is 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000, which is different.

What happens here is:

- Your C implementation uses four bytes to store `int` and eight bytes to store `double`.
- `data.d_val = 0;` sets all eight bytes to zero, so the bytes are 0000000000000000<sub>16</sub>.
- `data.int_val = INT_MAX;` sets the first four bytes to 7FFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>, leaving the second four bytes set to zero.
- Your C implementation stores the low bytes of a `double` first, so the bytes are 000000007FFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>. (The high bytes have the zeros set to `data.d_val = 0;`, the low bytes have the value set by `data.int_val = INT_MAX;`.) In the format used for `double` in your C implementation, IEEE-754 binary64, this encodes the value 7FFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>−1022−52</sup>, which is 1.0609978949885705117144445632550356231298636402913102795510726015675347183162029049070121453383892718022297358702472142033429414418721962620828783652689149189601777821806309400611506485053075432332671816493165493341275063746802067039789157235638508997666661403705017238515006667713911332277766673294515374571829472931091372817029586417037121435614677969705506719408696628686764380421773878776873568700216950700237625651794289820868998112187026624138685271707758982904094132557202196209188604809998941344964388684384772795893506049836847950409851073237758981680115344917689272539447810238141808009965510497366640491315341686473773141147356140881921781408044814178605913644069525350835948013163888157296150336506844976173190298052162461317493580281734466552734375•10<sup>−314</sup>. This so small that, when formatted with the `%f` format, it is printed as “0.000000”.
- `data.d_val = __DBL_MAX__;` sets the eight bytes of `d_val` to 7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>, which encodes the maximum finite `double` value, 2<sup>1024</sup>−2<sup>971</sup>, which is 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.
- `data.int_val = 0;` sets the low four bytes to zeros, so the bytes corresponding `d_val` are then 7FEFFFFF00000000<sub>16</sub>, which encodes the value 179769227765543015871544843204898548561652852981845720830741485657701606177416873137818677866537230765451463672297559953407043753842793767107723942762853526789169461948323286682454336232649253620483947928451548544466350813686932742283772637216475668546847194115014476747609904655041063083840261631978879582208.
- Formatting the latter with `%f` prints “179769227765543015871544843204898548561652852981845720830741485657701606177416873137818677866537230765451463672297559953407043753842793767107723942762853526789169461948323286682454336232649253620483947928451548544466350813686932742283772637216475668546847194115014476747609904655041063083840261631978879582208.000000”, which is clearly different from the maximum finite `double` value.

Do not use `__DBL_MAX__`. It is intended for internal implementation use. Use `DBL_MAX`, which is specified by the C standard.